# Simple App Engine Query Invalid

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I'm getting an 'Invalid GQL query string' with this seemingly trivial GQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Event WHERE firstPlayer='glowingEthers' OR secondPlayer='glowingEthers'
```

It works fine when the OR clause is removed, for either property. These properties for the Event table are mutually exclusive (no event has both firstPlayer and secondPlayer set to the same player).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GQL doesn't have an `OR` operator (as noted [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference)). Since you've stated the result sets are mutually exclusive, you should perform two queries (one for firstPlayer and one for secondPlayer) and join them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help (just knowing mySQL) ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM Event 
WHERE 1 
AND (firstPlayer='glowingEthers' OR secondPlayer='glowingEthers')
```

Comment: OP is using GQL and a common trap is to assume that SQL will work here. In most cases it doesn't